# Quantidade de colunas em impressoras matricial e térmica

Tags: php, impressora

Estou gerando um arquivo de texto para ser impresso em impressoras matriciais e térmicas. O arquivo é impresso pelo DOS e gostaria de saber a quantidade de colunas que estas impressoras suportam.

Na térmica seria necessário imprimir duas vezes caso o cliente queira uma cópia do arquivo, já na impressora matricial poderia ser impresso um do lado do outro para economizar papel (caso a folha fosse maior).

Comment: A quantidade de colunas pode variar 40, 48 (se não houver mudança de fonte). A melhor maneira de saber é imprimindo.

Comment: qual a diferença de matricial e termica?

Comment: Tem outras medidas fora da faixa de 40 a 48 também, melhor especificar melhor o tipo de aplicação e impressora, ou deixar sua aplicação bem tolerante.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly matricial é agulha batendo na fita com tinta. a térmica não usa tinta, esquenta papel reagente (mais ou menos como o papel de fax). Impressão matricial dura anos e anos, térmica fica mais bonitinho na hora, mas depois de um tempo some tudo. Devia ser proibido usar térmica para recibos, tickets, coisa de banco etc. Tecnologia contra o povo (eu adoro impressora térmica, mas não pra documento).

Comment: matricial é aquelas de impressão de notas não fiscais certo?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly fiscal pode ser tambem. Se precisar de 2 ou 3 vias, precisa tirar nota na matricial, senao nao pega no carbono. Matricial e margarida sao as tecnologias que "batem" na folha fisicamente. NFe já é diferente, não existe nota física. O que se imprime é um documento auxiliar apenas.

Comment: Stefanio, se for impressão de bobina, tem bobina com 2 vias ou mais também, nao precisa ser lado a lado..

Comment: Sim, mas isso vai depender do equipamento do cliente, e lembrei agora também que tem modelos de folhas formulario continuo que sao cortadas ao meio. Tenho que verificar a quantidade de linhas destas folhas tambem